# IIS Rewrite part of url to url-Parameter

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the URL:

```
test.xy/Objekte/Haus-in-Rheinstetten
```

to

```
test.xy/Objekte/Haus-in.cfm?Ort=Rheinstetten
```

The part behind the second - in Haus-in-Rheinstetten convert to a url-Parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `web.config` file.
This file located in the folder of your site.
Example of rewriting rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to some page">
      <match url="http://some.site/some.page" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://other.site/other.page" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hallo Tair,
thank you, but i know this part of the solution.
But my Question ist the right match-Pattern to separate rheinstten( in the example) from the url and rewrite as url.paramter